# The right way to validate fields via hook_node_validate

Tags: 7, nodes, forms

Rather than creating a new field via the Field API, and as a quick workaround, I've added a simple text field to a content type that I'm now attempting to validate via `hook_node_validate()`. Unlike previous versions of Drupal, the value for this field is not simply available as `$node->field_name` or `$form['field_name']`, but instead as a nested array containing a variety of other information.

My question then is this: what is the 'correct' and therefore most future proof way to retrieve the value for this field? Am I supposed to be using the likes of `field_view_value()` or `field_view_field()`, or is it acceptable to simply reference `$node->field_name['und'][0]['value']` for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`field_get_items()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/field_get_items/7) is the one you're looking for:

```
$items = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_FIELD_NAME');
$first_value = $items[0]['value'];
```

It also takes care of language selection for you, so no need to worry about that one any more.